# Having issue while sorting and pulling large data (yajra datatables)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, large-data, yajra-datatable

I'm having an issue while pulling large data from `yajra datatable` server-side while applying the column sorting too.

For column sorting, I've used `get()` in the query builder. If I avoid it and use `orderBy`, it works fine and fetches records faster but the issue is column sorting doesn't work then.

```
$query = DB::table('clients');
        if(Auth::user()->role_id==2)
        {

           $clients=  $query->whereRaw('user_id',Auth::id());


               }
        else if(Auth::user()->role_id==3)
        {
            $getCompanyId = User::where('id',Auth::id())
                                ->first();

                   $clients=  $query->whereRaw('user_id',$getCompanyId['added_by']);                          


        }
       $clients= $query->orderBy('id');

        $clients = $query->select();
        $clients = $query->get();
        $datatables = datatables()->of($clients)


            ->addColumn('action', function ($clients) {

                       return '<button class="btn btn-xs buttonhover" data-id='.$clients->id.' data-backdrop="static" onclick="editClient(this);"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</button>

                                <button class="btn btn-xs buttonhover2" data-id='.$clients->id.' onclick="viewDetails(this);"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;View</button>

                              <button class="btn btn-xs buttondeletehover"data-id='.$clients->id.' onclick="confirmAlertBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</button>';
            })

            ->make(true);
        return $datatables;
```

Comment: what is the issue with select()

Answer (score 0):

Don't use of in datatables and don't get() data. Instead use eloquent to generate datatables object and query the sellect:

```
$users = User::query();
    return DataTables::eloquent($users)
    ->toJson();
```

Or just use order by to generate eloquent object:

```
$users = User::orderBy('id');
```

[Eloquent Data Source](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-eloquent#facade)